# Concatenating lists in Raku

Tags: raku

I'm looking for a simpler solution.

I have a list of prefixes with *corresponding* suffixes and a list of roots.

```perl6
my @prefixes = 'A'..'E';
my @suffixes = 'a'..'e';
my @roots = 1, 2;
```

I would like to make all the possible 'words': `A1a`, `B1b`...`A2a`...`E2e`.

```perl6
my @words;
for @roots -> $r {
    for @prefixes.kv -> $i, $p {
        my $s = @suffixes[$i];
        my $word = [~] $p, $r, $s;
        @words.push: $word;
    }
}
say @words; # [A1a B1b C1c D1d E1e A2a B2b C2c D2d E2e]
```

I suppose that it is possible to do it much easier using something like `zip` or `cross`, but can't figure out how...

Comment: `(("A".."E" Z "a".."e") X 1,2).map(-> (($a, $c), $b) { "$a$b$c" })`

Comment: or `(("A".."E" Z "a".."e") X 1,2).flat.map(* ~ * R~ *)`, though I wasn't sure that one would work out with regard to precedence/associativity until I tried it...

Comment: @Christoph Thanks! And indeed it seems that `Rop` has higher precedence than simply `op`. In the [docs](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#index-entry-R_reverse_meta_operator), there is only a cryptic phrase: "Associativity of operands is reversed as well".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A few more ways to write it:

---

```perl6
say @roots X[&join] (@prefixes Z @suffixes);
```

---

```perl6
say @roots.map({ |(@prefixes Z @suffixes)».join($_) });
```

---

```perl6
say @roots.map({ (@prefixes X~ $_) Z~ @suffixes }).flat;
```

---

```perl6
say (|@prefixes xx *) Z~ (@roots X~ @suffixes);
```

---

```perl6
my @formats = (@prefixes Z @suffixes).flat.map(* ~ '%s' ~ *);
say @formats X[&sprintf] @roots;
```

*(Note: This one prints them in a different order.)*

---

```perl6
say do for @roots -> $root {
    |do for (@prefixes Z @suffixes) -> [$prefix, $suffix] {
        $prefix ~ $root ~ $suffix
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the first solution is the clearest! And all the different solution to this question provide a mini-encyclopedia of Perl 6. :)

Answer (score 12):

My solution would be:

```
say @roots.map: |(@prefixes >>~>> * <<~<< @postfixes);
```

Create a WhateverCode for metaopping concatenation, slipping the result to get a `Seq` with only scalar values at the end.